# ActiveLdap Has ability to create relationship between OU has many Person and OU has many Groups

Tags: ruby, ldap

Is there a way to configure ActiveLdap with this type of scheme.

```
* dc=example,dc=com
|+ o=domain1.com,dc=example,dc=com
  \ 
   |+ ou=People,o=domain1.com,dc=example,dc=com
    \
     |- cn=user1,ou=People,o=domain1.com,dc=example,dc=com
     |- cn=user2,ou=People,o=domain1.com,dc=example,dc=com
     |- ...
   |+ ou=Groups,
    \
     |- cn=group1,ou=Groups,o=domain1.com,dc=example,dc=com
     |- cn=group2,ou=Groups,o=domain1.com,dc=example,dc=com
     |- ...
|- o=otherdomain.com,dc=example,dc=com
  \ 
   |+ ou=People,o=otherdomain.com,dc=example,dc=com
    \
     |- cn=user1,ou=People,o=otherdomain.com,dc=example,dc=com
     |- cn=user2,ou=People,o=otherdomain.com,dc=example,dc=com
     |- ...
   |+ ou=Groups,
    \
     |- cn=group1,ou=Groups,o=otherdomain.com,dc=example,dc=com
     |- cn=group2,ou=Groups,o=otherdomain.com,dc=example,dc=com
     |- ...
```

I try to use somthing like that:

```
class Domain < ActiveLdap::Base
  ldap_mapping :dn_attribute => 'o',
               :prefix => '',
               :classes => %w(inetdomainauthinfo top maildomain organization)
end
```

But i can't figure out how to create the Person.rb correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, thanks Kouhei.

```
class Domain < ActiveLdap::Base
  ldap_mapping :dn_attribute => 'o',
               :prefix => '',
               :classes => %w(inetdomainauthinfo top maildomain organization)

  def user(uid)
    User.find(uid, :prefix => "ou=People,o=#{o}")
  end

  def users
    User.all(:prefix => "ou=People,o=#{o}")
  end

  def group(cn)
    Group.find(cn, :prefix => "ou=Groups,o=#{o}")
  end

  def groups
    Group.all(:prefix => "ou=Groups,o=#{o}")
  end

end


class Group < ActiveLdap::Base
  ldap_mapping :dn_attribute => 'cn',
               :prefix => '',
               :classes => %w(inetlocalmailrecipient inetmailgroupmanagement
top inetmailgroup groupofuniquenames)

  def domain
    Domain.find(dn.rdns[2]['o'])
  end
end



class User < ActiveLdap::Base
  ldap_mapping :dn_attribute => 'uid',
               :prefix => '',
               :classes => %w(top userpresenceprofile inetadmin
organizationalperson person inetuser inetlocalmailrecipient inetorgperson
inetsubscriber inetmailuser)

  def domain
    Domain.find(dn.rdns[2]['o'])
  end
end
```